# Failed to push Some ref in repo?

Tags: git, github

Im pushing my edited code to my existing repo but got an error and that error is shown below ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Krcu.png)

can some one tell me how to solve this erro ? i deleted the file from github not from the terminal and also commited the changes.

i'm pushing the code on my existing repo and i expect that the code is pushed on github  without any error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+remote+contains+work+that+you+do+not+have+locally

Answer (score 0):

As I see from the attached screenshot, I don't see any staged changes.
Also you might want to pull any updates from the remote branch first using git pull then you can add changes and commit then push